# Mocking receiver functions in Go

Tags: unit-testing, go, mocking

I'm trying to unit test a receiver function that calls other receiver functions in that struct.

Let's say I want to test Three() and mock the call to two() in the following:

```
type MyStruct struct {
    a string
    b string
}

func (m *MyStruct) one() int {
    return 2
}

func (m *MyStruct) two() int {
    return m.one() * 2
}

func (m *MyStruct) Three() int {
    return m.two() * 2
}
```

I was following method two of the following [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19168875/393109).

I created a custom constructor for every single function that I wanted to unit test and overrode those methods with mocked versions. But I thought it may not be easy to maintain the code once the number of functions grow.

Is there any preferred way of mocking such functions? I wish the official documentation had some guidelines on how to mock things in different scenarios, similar to what mox on Python provides.

Also, note that I don't want to use a third party mocking library.

Comment: Why bother? I would think a unit test per method is more than enough. Think of a unit test on method "Three" like a mini integration test.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm trying to do. I want to mock all those calls, because I'm only testing the functionality of a particular function. Function "Three" could be just any function here. It's not necessarily an integrated test.

Comment: Why *I don't want to use a third party mocking library*? `unittest.mock` was be a third party library till python3.2 and in python2.7 you need always install it by `pip`.

Comment: Here's another approach with a full example that should make clear how it is possible to write testable code in Go: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48206430/828366

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mock functions in Go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19167970/mock-functions-in-go)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That is a really un-idiomatic way to test your stuff.
All this mocking might be needed in other languages, but
please don't do it in Go.

The natural way to test your code in the example you gave
would be: 1) Write a table driven test for `MyStruct.one`
and make sure you test all cases. Now that you know `one`
works perfectly fine 2) do the same with `MyStruct.two`.
Note that testing unexported stuff is possible, useful and
common in Go. Now there is no longer a need need to mock
some methods, just 3) write some table driven test for 
`MyStruct.Three` and check it works.

But maybe your methods `one` and `two` do fancier stuff, and
access the environment (filesystem, database, network) and
you do not want your tests of  `Three` to depend on that?
So refactor your code! Maybe `Three` should not be a method
of  `MyStruct` but a function which takes an `interface OneAndTwoer`
as an argument and your production code calls `Three` with "real"
MyStructs while your testcode calls it with InMemoryMyStrcuts
which do not depend on the environment?  You could call it a
mock, I'd call it a different implementation of an interface.

In your example it is simple to give advice: Use table driven 
tests for `one`, `two` and `Three` and do not mock.
For a more realistic problem the advice might be different but
it is hard to give a general advice without knowing the 
circumstances. Best general advice is: Take a look at the test in
the standard library where you'll find useful patterns for almost
every testing scenario.

Comment: Assume `one` does a network call  in this case how do you write test for `two` ?

Comment: @Siddhart Set up a test server with net/http/httptest.Server and let `one` do the "network call". I know: Some school teach "Unit-Test == does not access anything, no file system, no database, no network, no nothing". This is academic circlejerk and as such it is fine. In real life: How often do you run your unit tests on a system where no file system is available or you cannot call a local HTTP server?

Answer (score 2):

You can do a refactor to pass two as a func in `Three`, so that you can directly mock the input.

```golang
func main() {
    var ms MyStruct
    fmt.Println(ms.one())
    fmt.Println(ms.two())
    fmt.Println(ms.Three(ms.two))
}

type MyStruct struct {}

func (m *MyStruct) one() int {
    return 2
}

func (m *MyStruct) two() int {
    return m.one() * 2
}

func (m *MyStruct) Three(two func() int) int {
    return two() * 2
}
```