# How can I properly write the `Read` and `Write` the `net.Pipe()`

Tags: go

I'm trying out the `net.Pipe()`.  I thought writing the `"haha"` string and then reading it back might be a good experiment.

Here is my first version.  It blocks on the `Write`

```
func TestNetPipe(t *testing.T) {
    out1 := make([]byte, 10) 
    c1, c2 := net.Pipe()
    c1.Write([]byte("haha"))
    c2.Read(out1)
}
```

I tried to use a goroutine

```
func TestNetPipe(t *testing.T) {
    out1 := make([]byte, 10) 
    c1, c2 := net.Pipe()
    go func() {
        c1.Write([]byte("haha"))
    }() 
    fmt.Printf("%v\n", out1)
    c2.Read(out1)
    fmt.Printf("%v\n", out1)
}
```

It works. But I felt there is no guarantee that the `Read` will read the whole `"haha"` string. It might only read the `"hah"` part.

I'm wondering if there is a better way to demo the usage of `net.Pipe()`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use [`ReadAll`](https://golang.org/pkg/io/ioutil/#ReadAll) function from package `io/ioutil`.

As `ReadAll` function blocks until EOF the following code needs no synchronization of goroutines. The call of `close` method causes the EOF on the stream.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "net"
)

func main() {
    r, w := net.Pipe()
    go func() {
        w.Write([]byte("haha"))
        w.Close()
    }()
    b, err := ioutil.ReadAll(r)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf(err.Error())
    }
    fmt.Println(string(b))
}
```

[<kbd>Playground</kbd>](https://play.golang.org/p/LxmAoL2m43)