# How do I mock a function from another package?

Tags: go

Package A

```
func Validate(){
    db.CheckPresent() //how to mock this function which is in another package
    return nil
}
```

I am writing test case in Golang to test a function which calls `CheckPresent()` function from another package. How to mock `CheckPresent()` fuction?

Comment: You can't. You'd need to either wrap it in a type with an interface you can mock, or put the function in a variable so you can swap out the implementation for testing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mock functions in Go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19167970/mock-functions-in-go)

Answer (score 0):

```
type Checker interface {
    CheckPresent()
}

// mock
type checkerMock struct {
}

func (m checkerMock) CheckPresent() {
}

// production code
type handler struct {
    db Checker
}

func New(db Checker) *handler {
    return &handler{
        db: db,
    }
}

func (h handler) Validate() {
    h.db.CheckPresent() 
    return nil
}
```

Comment: I have a constraint not to change Production Code. Should i use fake or stubs in that scenario?

Comment: I need to see your code to answer. For example, if `db.CheckPresent()` works with db you can use `https://github.com/DATA-DOG/go-sqlmock`

Comment: So how are you gonna run this ```Validate()``` function anywhere else like in some other package. As far as I can see, you will have to create a new instance of ```Handler```, then how are you gonna assign the field ```db Checker```. I feel it will be a circular dependency problem @dmitry-harnitski

Comment: It is advised to create struct instances in application composition root (main function). Search for `Composition Root` and `Dependency Injection` patterns. They are well documented for .NET, but work great for Go as well.  These patterns are not part of vanilla GO, but that is the best way to make your code unit testable.

Comment: I went through some sources on DI and Composition Root specifically for golang, but couldn't figure out my problem. ```https://go.dev/play/p/0tThHdNl2ii``` . Can you please go through this dummy code and tell me how do I use this ```Test``` function in the main.go file. More specifically how can I create an instance for ```AStruct```. I am sorry to bother you more, but this has been bothering me for a couple of weeks now. And we have a deadline coming. I am sorry again, but help will be appreciated. @dmitry-harnitski

Comment: Sorry for delay. https://go.dev/play/p/qBf5bERS6-Y - you need to have 2 entities. One that does the work, and it is also subject to test. And second one is dependency with side effects that break tests. Second one has two implementations for same interface - real that is injected in main.go and fake used in tests.

Comment: What if we have multiple sibling functions that are calling each other. Like ```a()``` calls ```b()``` and ```b()``` calls ```c()``` and ```c()``` calls ```d()```, then we have to implement like 4 interfaces to unit test ```a(), b() and c()```? @dmitry-harnitski