# testing function calling using var declaration to mock the result

Tags: go

I'm testing a function which called another function in Go. And here's what I have

```
package b

type b struct {...}

func (b *b) functionB(){...}
```

```
package a

import "b"

type a struct {...}

func (a *a) functionA() {
    b := b{...}
    b.functionB()
    ...
}
```

I want to modify the function declaration in `b` like this:

```
package b

type b struct {...}

var functionB = b.FuncInB

func (b *b) FuncInB(){...}
```

so that I can mock the return of `functionB` in a. However, I got error message in a that says `b.functionB` is undefined because it should be the function of b object. How can I make this work?

Comment: You should redesign and stop mocking. You should test package b and assume it is working correctly while testing package a and just call methods of b. Mocking is a bad technique, especially in Go.

Comment: @Volker I'm creating unit testing for my function and need to do this. I see another post about mocking function like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19167970/mock-functions-in-go

Comment: It is not possible to call `b.functionB`, whether it's a function or a method, from `a` because it is *not* [exported](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Exported_identifiers).

Comment: "[I] need to do this". That's why I recommend to redesign because you should not do this.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a definition of one package in another package you have to export it. This is done by letting the definition start with a capital letter. Your type should be defined like this:

```
type B struct {...}
```

You cannot access a function via its type. This line

```
var functionB = b.FuncInB
```

will not work, as you can refer to the function only from an existing struct. You shoule remove this line and call it differently (see below).

Your package a has now two minor issues. When you want to use struct `B` from package `b` you have to either refer to it like this `b.B`

```
import "b"

b.B{...}
```

or make a dot import for package b:

```
import . "b"

B{...}
```

The last thing is, that you shadow the package name when assigning a variable with the same name as the package. In that, you should use a different variable name:

```
func (a *a) functionA() {
    myB := b{...}
    myB.FunctionB()
    ...
}
```

So in the end, your packages should look like this:

```golang
package b

type B struct {
    // ...
}

func (b *B) FuncInB() {
    // ...
}
```

```golang
package a

import "b"

type a struct {
    // ...
}

func (a *a) functionA () {
    myB := B {
        // ...
    }
    myB.functionB()
    // ...
}
```

Comment: thank you for your reply but my problem is about the declaration using var in `b`

Comment: Your are welcome. It is difficult to answer, because you state your problem in a very abstract way. If you could provide more details of what you actually want to achieve, it would be easier to answer.