# Golang Unit Testing

Tags: unit-testing, go

I am stuck on how to write tests. I have following public function. `GetAccountNumber()` has its own logic.  I would like to return a mock value for `GetAccountNumber()`. In Java, I could do `when(object.method()).thenReturn("returnValue")`. Is something similar available for go how can I accomplish that. I am going through bunch of go documentation but have not found anything useful yet.

```
func GetConfigName() string {
    var configName string
    accountNumber := GetAccountNumber()
    switch *accountNumber {
    case "123":
        configName = "test1"
    case "456":
        configName = "test2"

    return configName
}
```

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62208922/3473875) help?

Comment: Generally speaking, mocks are not required--a simple stub is usually enough. But it's hard to say, since we can't see what `GetAccountNumber` does.

Comment: @Flimzy I might be naive to ask this. Isn't the whole point of stubbing/mocking is that I don't need to know what GetAccountNumber does internally and just know that it returns a string.

Comment: No. The point of stubbing/mocking is not to be ignorant of what a function does--it is to limit what you test. If you don't stub out `GetAccountNumber`, then your test is _also_ testing `GetAccountNumber`, and a failure in your test won't tell you what's broken.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

For writing a unit test case for this function, we need to see the `GetAccountNumber()` function definition first.

Please see "[Unit Testing made easy in Go](https://medium.com/rungo/unit-testing-made-easy-in-go-25077669318)" for more information on writing unit test cases in Go.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/26402641)

Comment: There is perticular problem mentioned in the error, I think he need to learn about writing Unit test cases. I personally found that helpful when I was learning Golang. That's why I shared that.

Comment: Thanks @AlokTripathi, you are correct I am learning go and also have to dig in the code base that my team has that does not have good coverage. I am trying to learn go along with writing unit tests. Isn't the whole point of stubbing/mocking is that we don't need to know what GetAccountNumber does internally and only know that it returns a string