# How to write a unit test for hyperledger/fabric-sdk-go?

Tags: go, hyperledger-fabric, chaincode

How to write a unit test for the following code
**The GetBook function is a function in chaincode code**

```
func (svc *service) GetBook(_ context.Context, id string) (*Entity, error) {
    res, err := svc.contract.EvaluateTransaction("GetBook", id)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("error on evaluate transaction: %w", err)
    }

    var rsp Entity

    err = json.Unmarshal(res, &rsp)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("error on unmarshal json: %w", err)
    }

    return &rsp, nil
}
```

Comment: does this help ? https://stackoverflow.com/a/19168875/4466350

Answer (score 2):

To run unit test for chaincode, you need to use [counterfeiter](https://github.com/maxbrunsfeld/counterfeiter) which you can use to generate all the mock interfaces of contractapi and chaincodeStubs. This can go in your xxxTest.go file

```
//go:generate counterfeiter -o mocks/transaction.go -fake-name TransactionContext . transactionContext
type transactionContext interface {
    contractapi.TransactionContextInterface
}

//go:generate counterfeiter -o mocks/chaincodestub.go -fake-name ChaincodeStub . chaincodeStub
type chaincodeStub interface {
    shim.ChaincodeStubInterface
}
```

and import the generated mock interfaces to write unit-test

```
func TestReadCashWallet(t *testing.T) {
    chaincodeStub := &mocks.ChaincodeStub{}
    transactionContext := &mocks.TransactionContext{}
    transactionContext.GetStubReturns(chaincodeStub)

    cashWalletContract := chaincode.CashWalletContract{}
    cashwallet := &chaincode.CashWallet{
        ID: "id",
    }
    bytes, err := json.Marshal(cashwallet)
    require.NoError(t, err, "error json marshal")

    chaincodeStub.GetStateReturns(bytes, nil)
    res, err := cashWalletContract.ReadCashWallet(transactionContext, "id")
    require.EqualValues(t, cashwallet, res)

}
```

You have to mock the all the shim functions actions such as GetState, GetHistoryForKey, PutState etc.

More detailed examples are provided in the fabric-samples [here](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples). You can clone this and check out the full code example with the usage of counterfeiter and unit test example in the **asset-transfer-private-data/chaincode-go**

Comment: I know how to write Chinese test code
The following code communicates with Chincode using sdk
I wrote a test code for China
But I want to write for the following code which is in sdk

Answer (score -1):

````
import (
    "context"
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-go/pkg/client/msp"
    "github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-go/pkg/gateway"
)
func (svc *service) GetBook(_ context.Context, id string) (*Entity, error) {
    res, err := svc.contract.EvaluateTransaction("GetBook", id)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("error on evaluate transaction: %w", err)
    }

    var rsp Entity

    err = json.Unmarshal(res, &rsp)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("error on unmarshal json: %w", err)
    }

    return &rsp, nil
}```
````